# Scheduled download from MSDN

Tags: download, file-transfer, scheduled-tasks, bittorrent, msdn

How does one schedule a download from MSDN?

I have a cap of 20GB per month that I'm permitted to download during peak hours, 7am to 1am. I can download as much as I like between 1am and 7am.

Given downloads from MSDN for operating systems and the like are often 2-4GB I cannot really download them during peak hours. How do I schedule these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to schedule downloads from MSDN, currently.

Comment: Marked this as the answer for now. If it changes in the future, I'll move the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One thought that sprang to mind: schedule a torrent from somewhere. The trouble is knowing which torrents are legitimate.

I also found if you search for "direct link" or "direct download" for your product of interest you can find direct links that can then be scheduled with a download manager.